# Obtaining Json from PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to make a query in php that returns a list of rows and thought of using json, I want to retrieve the data in Android Studio but that's another problem.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];

$host_name  = "host";
$database   = "database";
$user_name  = "username";
$password   = "password";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

$select = "SELECT titulo,contenido,fecha,prioridad FROM tasker WHERE encargado='$username' AND estado = 0 ORDER BY fecha";

$result = $connect->query($select);
$rows = array();

while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo json_encode($rows);
} else {
    echo $rows;
}
$connect->close();
?>
```

Do you guys have any idea why it dosn't work correctly?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But returning a different data type when there are no rows is an anti-pattern. Return an empty array instead.

Comment: `Do you guys have any idea why it dosn't work correctly?`-> what is not working correctly?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: What is your error/errormessage?

Comment: Removed your connection data. Never do post actual connections!
Also your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. (try posting `'; DELETE FROM tasker;--` as username and you will see)

Comment: It returns an empty array

Comment: Try to iterate directly on query() result.

Comment: Maybe you are getting an error connecting. I see you don't check if the connection was successful. Try:
    /* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (!$mysqli->query("SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php

Comment: If I change the query to this: $select = "SELECT * from tasker WHERE estado=0 AND encargado ='user'"; it works, it seems it only fails when I use variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not include a self contained example.

Assuming that the code you posted is json.php, what we're missing are, say, index.php (that calls json.php) and SQL code to (re)create a basic tasker table.

When I use this SQL...

```
CREATE TABLE `tasker` (
    id INT(11) UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    titulo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT "title",
    contenido VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT "content",
    fecha DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT "date",
    prioridad INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT "priority",
    encargado VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COMMENT "leader username",
    estado INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT "state",
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `tasker` VALUES (NULL, 'Mr.', 'test1', NOW(), 1, "leader1", 0);
INSERT INTO `tasker` VALUES (NULL, 'Mrs.', 'test2', NOW(), 2, "leader1", 0);
INSERT INTO `tasker` VALUES (NULL, 'Ms.', 'test3', NOW(), 3, "leader2", 0);
```

...with this index.php...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Green_Sam</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="json.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

..then the result, when I visit index.php and search for "leader1" is:

```
[{"titulo":"Mr.","contenido":"test1","fecha":"2017-11-07 11:40:23","prioridad":"1"},{"titulo":"Mrs.","contenido":"test2","fecha":"2017-11-07 11:40:25","prioridad":"2"}]
```

In a comment you describe the problem as "It returns an empty array".
This would mean my PHP/SQL code fixes the problem.
But again, it's hard to say, since you did not post a self contained example that fails for you.

By the way, where you use...
$username = $_POST['username'];
...instead use...
$username = htmlspecialchars ($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES);
...or something similar to prevent SQL injections and similar problems.

Also, I suggest you **always** post examples where you clearly enabled error/warning reporting with:

```
error_reporting (-1);
ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');
```

Then at least we know it's less likely you ran into any basic errors related to, for example, connecting to the database.